# Docker Compose based Gitlab CI - Pipe error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

## The problem

I have made a project with **docker compose**. It works well on localhost. I want to use this base to test or analyze code with Gitlab Runner. I solved a lot of problems, like install docker compose, run and build selected containers and run commands in container. The first job ran and success (!!!), but the following jobs failed before "before_script":

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
>   ...
>   Error response from daemon: Conflict.
>   ...
>   Error response from daemon: Conflict.

I don't understand why. What do I do wrong? I repeat: the first job of the pipeline runs well with **"success"** message! Each other jobs of the pipeline fail.

Full output:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.4.0 (ef0b1a6)
  on XXX Runner (fdc0d656)
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image docker:dind ID=sha256:5096e5a0cba00693905879b09e24a487dc244b56e8e15349fd5b71b432c6ec9ffor docker service...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image docker:dind ID=sha256:5096e5a0cba00693905879b09e24a487dc244b56e8e15349fd5b71b432c6ec9f for docker service...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/runner-fdc0d656-project-35-concurrent-0-docker" is already in use by container "80918876ffe53e33ce1f069e6e545f03a15469af6596852457f11dbc7a6c5b58". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image docker:dind ID=sha256:5096e5a0cba00693905879b09e24a487dc244b56e8e15349fd5b71b432c6ec9f for docker service...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/runner-fdc0d656-project-35-concurrent-0-docker" is already in use by container "80918876ffe53e33ce1f069e6e545f03a15469af6596852457f11dbc7a6c5b58". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/runner-fdc0d656-project-35-concurrent-0-docker" is already in use by container "80918876ffe53e33ce1f069e6e545f03a15469af6596852457f11dbc7a6c5b58". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

## Files

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
# Select image from https://hub.docker.com/r/_/php/
image: docker:latest

# Services
services:
    - docker:dind

stages:
    - build
    - test
    - deploy

cache:
    key: ${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME}
    untracked: true
    paths:
        - vendor
        - var

variables:
    DOCKER_CMD: docker exec --user user bin
    COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT: 300

before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache py-pip bash
    - pip install docker-compose
    - touch ~/.gitignore
    - bin/docker-init.sh
    - cp app/config/parameters.gitlab-ci.yml app/config/parameters.yml
    - cp app/config/nodejs_parameters.yml.dist app/config/nodejs_paramteres.yml
    - chmod -R 777 app/cache app/logs var
    # Load only binary and mysql
    - docker-compose up -d binary mysql

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - ${DOCKER_CMD} composer install -n
        - ${DOCKER_CMD} php app/console doctrine:database:create --env=test --if-not-exists
        - ${DOCKER_CMD} php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --env=test

codeSniffer:
    stage: test
    script:
        - ${DOCKER_CMD} bin/php-cs-fixer fix --dry-run --config-file=.php_cs

database:
    stage: test
    script:
        - ${DOCKER_CMD} php app/console doctrine:mapping:info --env=test
        - ${DOCKER_CMD} php app/console doctrine:schema:validate --env=test
        - ${DOCKER_CMD} php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test

unittest:
    stage: test
    script:
        - ${DOCKER_CMD} bin/phpunit -c app --debug

deploy_demo:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploy to staging server"
    environment:
        name: staging
        url: https://staging.example.com
    only:
        - develop

deploy_prod:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploy to production server"
    environment:
        name: production
        url: https://example.com
    when: manual
    only:
        - master
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "2"

services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "${HTTP_PORT}:80"
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - elasticsearch
            - binary
        links:
            - binary:php
        volumes:
            - ".:/var/www"
            - "./app/config/docker/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf"
            - "${BASE_LOG_DIR}/nginx:/var/log/nginx"

    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.6
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: test
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
        ports:
            - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
        volumes:
            - "${BASE_LOG_DIR}/mysql:/var/log/mysql"
            - "${BASE_MYSQL_DATA_DIR}:/var/lib/mysql"
            - "./app/config/docker/mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf"

    elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:1.7.6
        ports:
            - "${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}:9200"
        volumes:
            - "${BASE_ELASTICSEARCH_DATA_DIR}:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"

    binary:
        image: fchris82/kunstmaan-test
        container_name: bin
        volumes:
            - ".:/var/www"
            - "${BASE_LOG_DIR}/php:/var/log/php"
            - "~/.ssh:/home/user/.ssh"
        tty: true
        environment:
            LOCAL_USER_ID: ${LOCAL_USER_ID}
```

`config.toml`

```
[[runners]]
  name = "XXX Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.xxx.xx/"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem. I spoilt the configuration. If you use **dind** service in `.gitlab-ci.yml` then don't use `/var/run/docker.sock` volume in `config.toml` file OR vica versa if you use "socket" method, don't use the **dind** service.

More informations: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html